# security of lubuntu VM

Tags: security, virtual-machine, lubuntu

I use a Lubuntu 12.04 installed inside a VM to browse less than safe websites with Chrome. I would like to know of the relevant security risks this setup poses to my home network. I do not store anything on the VM itself, so I couldn't care less if it's compromised. But I do care if malware spreads to other parts of my home network. I have 2 Windows 7 PC's and 2 Macs.

Comment: Since you already use a VM it's easy to create a snapshot and start from this snapshot every time. Even if VM is compromised, it lasts only for that session. That way you cannot avoid malware, but you can easily get rid of it (unless the malware already spread to the other computers).

Comment: 1) What VM do you use? (you can isolate the guest in VMWare for example) | 2) What kind of network connection do you use in your vm software? (NAT may not be the best...)